# "American Monte-Carlo"

Tags: statistics, random-variables, mathematical-modeling, monte-carlo

I heard this name in a discussion on market modeling. As I understood from the context, this is an optimization of the classical Monte Carlo method.

Unfortunately, Google does not know such a name. Perhaps it's just that top of serach "dirty" by the 2011 Hollywood film with same name.

Could you point me in the right direction - where can I read about this method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean something like "Monte Carlo modeling of American options"?

Comment: I am sure, and I sure has a another special name. But this is precisely the optimized (perhaps for large dimensions) Monte Carlo method

Comment: Well, I have done a lot of Monte Carlo simulation and I have never heard this term.  If you can't supply a reference or any context, I'd assume you either misheard it or that it was a term that only had meaning in a precise context.

Comment: To lulu's point, when we add "American" to the search for Monte Carlo, we get references to pricing options which have different results for American vs European. Can you link to the article where you saw this phrase?

Comment: you should search  "Longstaff-Schwartz Monte Carlo" instead. In fact, the pricing of American Option is the first application of "Longstaff-Schwartz Monte Carlo", that's why later people usually call (by mistake) the method American Monte Carlo.